# RequireJS define callback returning wrong module dependencies

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I'm having a very strange and frustrating problem with RequireJS.  When I call require for a module with a list of dependencies, all dependencies available in the callback reference a single module.  This is probably easier to explained with code:

Including require.js script (with no data-main attribute)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/common/require.min.js" ></script>
```

Below that I include require my main.js (used in all pages of the site) which in the callback requires my page specific js.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  require(['/js/require/main.js'], function () {
    require(['page/home_page']);
  });
</script>
```

main.js

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'js/require'
});

requirejs(['base'],
function() {
  var base = require('base');
  base.init();
});
```

home_page.js

```
define(['home','searchbar'], function (home,searchbar){

  console.log(home.init == searchbar.init); // This is always true !!!

  home.init();
  searchbar.init();
});
```

home.js

```
define(function(){
  this.init = function(){
    console.log('in home page'); 
  }
  return this;
});
```

searchbar.js

```
define(function(){
  this.init = function(){
    console.log('Now in the searchbar init')
  }
  return this;
});
```

The issue is in home_page.js both modules home and searchbar reference the same thing.  What's strange is that now that I've simplified this example, it seems pretty random which one it chooses.  Most times it's searchbar but every few refreshes it will be home.

Anyone have an ideas?  Is it something terribly obvious?

EDIT:  Simplified example and provided all module source.

Comment: Is that your full `requirejs.config`? Can you show the searchbar, home and account module files?

Comment: @PaulGrime, question has been modified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning to `this` in both modules. This is not a good idea (excuse the pun). `this` will possibly be the `window` object in both cases. You could check by adding a

```
window.init === searchbar.init
```

test.

Rewrite the modules to return unique objects, like so:

```
define(function() {
    return {
        init: function() {
            console.log('in home page'); 
        }
    };
});
```

and

```
define(function() {
    return {
        init: function() {
            console.log('Now in the searchbar init'); 
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Blah, yep, that's what it was.  Don't know why but I thought the callbacks might have their own scope.